# Python - mapping dictionary keys to string integers avoiding duplicates

Tags: python, dictionary

I need to create a dictionary in order to do some mapping, like so:

```
mapping = {x: x.split('_')[0] for x in G}
```

which returns:

```
{'0_cerebellum': '0', '1_cerebellum': '1', '0_cortex': '0', '1_cortex': '1'}
```

but this will get me duplicates and I need unique string ints as values.

---

Now, once the split class 'cerebellum' reaches its last 'n' string index ('1' here), how do I keep mapping starting from n+1, n+2 (and so on) values for split class 'cortex', ending up with:

```
{'0_cerebellum': '0', '1_cerebellum': '1', '0_cortex': '2', '1_cortex': '3'}
```

Comment: Would getting the first character of the key and then using it as the value, work? If the range is too big, you could number them like `'001', '002'`,etc.

Comment: unfortunately no. I need to have proper indexing as value, starting from 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 and so on. 001, 002 won't do it, I'm afraid...

Comment: Why does `1_cortex` get the value of `3`? Because the highest number seen so far was `2`?

Comment: yes, because it was 2

Comment: @8-BitBorges As I understand, the answer I posted does what you want, just let me know if I misunderstood :)

Comment: it does, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand, this should get your result, using `enumerate`.

```
G = ['0_cerebellum', '1_cerebellum', '0_cortex', '1_cortex']
mapping = {key: str(uniqueNum) for uniqueNum,key in enumerate(G)}
```

Output:

```
{'0_cerebellum': '0', '1_cerebellum': '1', '0_cortex': '2', '1_cortex': '3'}
```

Answer (score -1):

use `enumerate()`:

```py
>>> l = ['test', 'foo', 'None', 'Bar']
>>> enumerate(l)
<enumerate object at 0x00000258DE241340>
>>> list(enumerate(l))
[(0, 'test'), (1, 'foo'), (2, 'None'), (3, 'Bar')]
```

this is your finally code:

```py
mapping = {x: str(i) for i, x in enumerate(G)}
```